# Whistling copyrighted music on youtube

Tags: copyright, dmca, youtube

Without going into too much detail as to the why's and wherefore's of the question (I'll put it at the bottom, question first), I am curious about the copyright laws regarding whistling copyrighted music in a youtube video. It wouldn't be the focus of the video, but it would be a passing part of the video. I'm wondering about the ability to monetize such content.

As for why I'm curious about this, I've recently been thinking about starting a youtube channel. I have no delusions of grandeur, and I don't want to be presumptuous, but it serves to be prepared. I tend to whistle, and without trying to sound cocky, I'm quite good at whistling music. The channel would be man-cave workshop type content, among other things, and I would like to include bits where you can hear me whistling or singing along with the music that I'm listening to (the video music would be non-copyrighted, but I would quiet it to hear the whistling or singing). It would be short snippets, no more than 5 or 10 seconds, and you wouldn't hear the music that I'm hearing because I use headphones. If I ever got to a point where I *could* monetize my channel, would this prevent me from doing that?

Comment: The owner of the copyright could sue for damages, though that doesn't mean that they would.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's illegal. Just like singing/whistling happy birthday in public (used to be) illegal. You could be sued for untold amount of damages that could ruin your life forever (in theory).

If you whistle a mashup remix then it's legal as long as it's different enough from the original that you can't tell that they are the same song anymore.

Yes anyone can sue you if you piss them off. Disney doesn't sue all the people who sing covers of their songs because it's bad for business to piss off your fans, but they can sue if they feel like it.

This is more common sense than anything else but I suggest you look into fair use copyright law since there is a lot of misconception about it.

https://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/fair-use/what-is-fair-use/

Comment: Aside: it was probably never *actually* illegal to sing "Happy Birthday" -- at least not during our lifetimes, or even our parents'. Warner Bros was just over-asserting its rights.

Comment: So basically, it would *probably* be ok, but they *could* complain if they felt so inclined. It wouldn't be a mashup, I whistle or sing along as I'm listening, but at the very least I would consider whistling to be a derivative. Also, like I said, it would be a 10 second portion of a 15+ minute video, and would certainly not be the focus of the video, just of that 10 seconds.

Comment: @cHao I'll agree it's unlikely that they would sue individuals for singing it in public. However, I've heard stories of restaurants being sued for singing it. I don't trust this link but it's the what I found from a quick search. http://fun107.com/restaurant-sued-for-singing-happy-birthday-yes-it-happened/ I remember reading on wikipedia that there was a lot of debate for who actually owned the copyright and whether or not it was valid.

Comment: @HaLo2FrEeEk It's very Unlikely that they would complain in a civil manner. The way these companies usually pick some of these options 1. Sue you. 2. Demonetize your video. 3. Steal all profit from your video. Don't believe me? Look at what Nintendo has done in the past on YouTube (I love Nintendo but they were just being awful)

Comment: @HaLo2FrEeEk Here's an example of just how anal and pointless it can get. https://kotaku.com/super-mario-maker-exposes-more-youtube-copyright-stupid-1727321308 Don't be so lax about it. When it comes to YouTube always err on the side of caution. Remember rule #1 YouTube don't care about its creators. Somebody puts in 3 complaints = your channel is deleted. It doesn't matter who does it. I can put in the 3 complains with 0 proof and your channel is deleted.

Comment: @LateralTerminal: I don't just mean WB wouldn't sue. I mean *there is no infringement* in singing it, not even infringement that would be dismissed as fair use. The copyright WB had was for a book in which the song appeared, and possibly for a particular arrangement of the song...not for the song itself. There may never have been an actual copyright on the song (copyright wasn't automatic back then), but even if there were, it would have expired by 1921.

Comment: I can think of at least one example of a popular youtuber singing a copyrighted song (Your Man by Josh Turner, he was singing the part that goes "baby lock the doors and turn the lights down low", a capella.) It was a voiceover during a portion of sped-up video. I'm sure there are others I'm not remembering at the moment. By popular I mean he has nearly 800,000 subscribers and puts up a new video almost daily.

Comment: @cHao: The song "Good morning to all" [the first song with the tune that was re-purposesd as "Happy birthday"] was written in 1893.  A book which notes that the song was also known as "Happy birthday to you" was published while the song was under copyright, but predates by over a year the first official authorized publication of the "Happy birthday" lyrics in 1935 (likely not coincidentally, the last your "Good morning to all" was under copyright).  I don't think any hard proof exists as to why anyone would have associated the tune with the title "Happy birthday to you" prior to 1935, but...

Comment: @cHao: ...I find absurdly implausible the notion that anyone who would have associated the song with that title wouldn't also have associated it with the lyrics that would result from replacing "Good morning" with "Happy birthday", "Children" with someone's name, and the final word "all" with "you".