# Can humming a bar of music be considered copyright infringement?

Tags: copyright, fair-use

I recently saw [a tweet](https://twitter.com/sssniperwolf/status/1066086219803615233) claiming a video got a DMCA claim based on humming a part of a song.

Can uploading a (monetized) video of humming a bar or two of copyrighted music be considered as copyright infringement, or is it fair use?

Comment: A big problem here is that "fair use" is a set of guidelines for a court rather than a solid and dependable set of rules. So unless a court has ruled the answer to the question "is this fair use" is can only be somewhere between "probably" and "probably not".

Comment: [Bar of music](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bar#Noun) - *"24. (music) A vertical line across a musical staff dividing written music into sections, typically of equal durational value. Synonym: measure". 25. (music) One of those musical sections.*

Comment: But is its use here idiomatic (not a rhetorical question)?

Comment: For such a short melodic snippet, it's probably possible to find a work in the public domain with the same melody, and argue that the snippet does not enjoy copyright protection because it was itself copied from the public domain.  As far as I could tell, the tweet doesn't link to the actual video, so it's not clear whether the excerpt was in this case "a bar or two" or longer.

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes, it's idiomatic.  In this case it's sense 25, not 24.  For example, the first two bars of Lennon and McCartney's _Yesterday_ correspond to the lyrics "Yesterday, all my troubles seemed so...." (However, it is possible to change the length of a bar, usually by a factor of two, without changing the sound of the piece, so for music that is not written down people may reasonably disagree about the length of one bar.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen See https://www.reddit.com/r/Jokes/comments/2mgiez/took_me_a_while/

Comment: Any particular jurisdiction?

Comment: Isn't it the case that there are (at least) two copyrights involved? The published arrangement of the notes and a performance of the piece are distinct, and I'm pretty sure most of what gets sued over is reproduction of a performance. Humming couldn't violate that.

Comment: @JimMack Yes, there are two copyrights involved.  But you can just as well be sued (or at least ordered to pay the appropriate royalties) for performing those notes without paying the author of the music.  And in the case where those notes form part of another work, you can be sued for a fraction of your royalties.  Men At Work had this with "Down under", with the flute part quoting a couple of bars of "Kookaburra".

Comment: @Graham - Understood. But those kinds of suits revolve around published (and cynically, successful) songs that are said to infringe. I cannot imagine a DCMA takedown over someone humming a tune, and it always seems to be labels, not publishers, who issue these.

Comment: @JimMack True to some extent.  But it's also the case that the original author/publisher wouldn't have the clout to do this on their own.  Let's not forget that the person who wrote that tune deserves a living too.  The point of the DMCA isn't to stop people using copyrighted work outright, it's to stop people using copyrighted work to earn themselves a living without paying a penny to the copyright owners.  If you're not making money off it, mostly no-one cares - but if (as the OP says) the video is monetized, and if the song is important to the scene, they should pay their way.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/27440/whistling-copyrighted-music-on-youtube

Comment: @Graham "If you're not making money off it, mostly no-one cares": this is incorrect.  If you make copies of a sound recording freely available on the internet and you're not making any money from it, you're still providing a means for listeners to consume the music without generating revenue for the record label.  Even though you're not making money, _you're cutting into their sales revenue._  What they really _don't_ care about is whether you're making money.  What they _do_ care about is that they aren't.

Comment: @phoog Fair point.

Answer (score 23):

### Go to court and find out

There is no doubt that humming a tune and *recording* it (or performing it in public) is a [derivative work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_work) - a right reserved to the copyright owner.

Whether it is [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) depends on the specifics of the case. From the tweet, we simply don’t have enough information, however, at a guess, it is probably not fair use.

Fair use in law is

> Notwithstanding the provisions of sections 17 U.S.C. § 106 and 17 U.S.C. § 106A, the fair use of a copyrighted work, including such use by reproduction in copies or phonorecords or by any other means specified by that section, for purposes such as criticism, comment, news reporting, teaching (including multiple copies for classroom use), scholarship, or research, is not an infringement of copyright. In determining whether the use made of a work in any particular case is a fair use the factors to be considered shall include:
>
> 1. the purpose and character of the use, including whether such use is of a commercial nature or is for nonprofit educational purposes;
> 2. the nature of the copyrighted work;
> 3. the amount and substantiality of the portion used in relation to the copyrighted work as a whole; and
> 4. the effect of the use upon the potential market for or value of the copyrighted work.
>
> The fact that a work is unpublished shall not itself bar a finding of fair use if such finding is made upon consideration of all the above factors.

Most people miss “for purposes such as criticism, comment, news reporting, teaching (including multiple copies for classroom use), scholarship, or research,” - if you aren’t doing one of those things then you start behind the 8-ball when yo move to the 4 factor test. Note that the “criticism, comment, news reporting,” etc. must be *about* the copyrighted work - I can’t use your copyrighted work to, for example, parody a politician unless you are that politician.

Many people have **completely** the wrong idea about what copyright infringement and fair use actually are, in part because the use of music on YouTube is allowed, not because it’s fair use but, because YouTube was smart enough to negotiate **and pay for** a permissive licence with music producers. For a full explanation, see [this](https://youtu.be/1Jwo5qc78QU) video.

Comment: This isn't as inflexible as you're making it sound. Satire *has* been ruled fair use, some of the time, e.g. Blanch v. Koons. And "comment" covers a pretty broad range, it's totally possible that someone in the video said "oh, xyz reminds me of that song (humming)". Especially since "humming a bar in a YouTube video" is generally going to pass 4 by a large margin, and 3 unless it's a very short song.

Comment: @user3067860 it’s very flexible - it just isn’t as broad as most people think. Fair dealing is very inflexible but that gives it the advantage of being (more) definite. Fair use can capture some things fair dealing wouldn’t but it can also exclude some things that would be fair dealing. While fair use is no longer an affirmative defence (in the 9th circuit at least) its still a tricky defence to win against a determined and well-resourced author.

Comment: @user3067860 Where does Blanch v. Koons say that?

Comment: @Acccumulation it says you have to consider all of the factors including the examples.

Comment: The phrase "for purposes such as..." is not meant to be exhaustive, as implied by "such as".  The closer one's actions are to the things on the list, the more effectively one will be able to satisfy #1, but I think a key aspect is the extent to which other works would be substitutable.  If one were doing a video about a singer, including a 4-second clip of a famous song would help viewers associate the singer with songs they'd heard, even if they hadn't previously associate the singer's name with those songs.  Playing some royalty-free song which is kinda sorta in the same genre would...

Comment: ...be totally ineffective for that purpose.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the assertion that humming a tune is 'clearly' a derivative work. Derivative of what? Isn't it just a performance of the work? I suppose it depends on what you consider "the work" and whose copyright is being gored. Is humming "White Christmas" derivative of Bing Crosby's release? Or is it just a performance of an Irving Berlin tune? If the latter, how is it derivative?

Comment: @JimMack a recording of a performance is derivative of the written song. If no record is made then, yes, it’s just a performance (also something protected by copyright if done in public)

Comment: @J... that’s not how DMCA takedowns work. YouTube will scrupulously not make any assessment if there has been a copyright violation - that’s how they keep their “safe harbour”

Answer (score 5):

The only way for the hummer to find out definitively is to file a counter-notice that, assuming the copyright holder files an infringement lawsuit, argue fair use. There is a reasonable chance that a fair use defense will succeed. The main impediment to fair use is the alternative that the "copying" is commercial. However, educational and "commentary" fair uses don't have to be given away for free (otherwise, there would be no textbook market, and they'd have to give newspapers away). It is more likely that the tiny amount of money gained from Youtube ad revenue does not constitute a "commercial" use in the court's judgment. The amount of copying is trivial and it is highly transformative, factors that favor fair use. Without inspection of the usage in context we can only surmise that this constitutes a "commentary", another factor favoring fair use. It is also highly unlikely that it will have an effect on the market for the original song. A fair use analysis requires *balancing*, that is, the list of factors isn't a list of fatal poisons. *On balance*, this is most likely fair use.

This also resembles Lenz v. Universal Music, where the court found that the complainant has a duty to consider fair use, so it is possible that the copyright holder has put himself in jeopardy by filing the DMCA takedown.

Comment: Why wouldn't YouTube monetization be evidence of commercial use?

Comment: For the same reason that selling a textbook is not "evidence of commercial use". The purpose and character of the use is "to comment" or "to educate", not "to make a buck". It would be an interesting research question to discern what level of profiting the courts tolerate under fair use: a potential separate question, if you are interested.

Comment: I think you're conflating some different concepts here, as selling a textbook isn't even making a copy. Has a court ever endorsed this theory that selling advertisements on your copy of a copyrighted work doesn't constitute a commercial use if you're only making a tiny amount of money?

Comment: The author copies material, under fair usage, into his textbook. He receives royalties from the publisher, who send books to sellers for end-user distribution. The author intends to receive royalties. No court has ever endorsed the theory that copying into a textbook where the author receives royalties constitutes infringement because if=t is a "commercial use".

Comment: It probably was an automated take down notice--I wonder where that falls, relative to your last paragraph.

Comment: @user6726 That seems like a needlessly long way of saying, "No."

Answer (score -2):

Broadly if the original is recognisable from the upload, there's a question of infringement. Fair use would include artistic, critical or academic comment or - possibly - the fact that the passage happened to be playing in the background of your wedding video.

Here, though, the Question turns on someone's definition of "monetized", that someone being first the copyright holder and then the court.

If that video is merely Posted on social media as celebration, you *prolly* won't be sued and if you were, you'd prolly walk free.

If the same video features the bride and groom falling over the cake and you sell it to someone who pays for bloopers, you might well be sued. More likely the people who paid you a token fee, then published the video for profit would be in court.

If you were paid extra because every movement the bride and groom made while falling over the cake just happened to match the music, you'd be more likely to lose but any of these cases might depend on the judge's mood and understanding.

I'm reminded of a case whose name I forget, in which a second person recorded some music and the judge awarded copyright damages to the first. Does that make sense? It was never clear whether the judge understood, but he certainly refused to accept the axiomatic argument that the passage at issue was a standard musical progression, not more eligible for copyright than might be 1-2-4-8-16…